# Disable or make the ability to click links or download attachments in received emails in microsoft outlook more difficult?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is there any setting to disable the ability to interact with links in an email or download attachments in microsoft outlook?

Comment: Did you try Trust Center settings?  I think this is the only setting in Outlook that can prevent some (not all) attachments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering the security in Outlook client, maybe we could try to move the unsafe message to junk folder via block specific sender or other junk option settings, so that unsafe message would be converted to plain text, which means we couldn't access the link and attachment there.
[image]

Comment: Does it have any update now?